# Understanding class object construction

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm reading clause 12.7 of N3797. The following example is given:

```
struct X { int i; };
struct Y : X { Y(); };  // non-trivial
struct A { int a; };
struct B : public A { int j; Y y; }; // non-trivial

extern B bobj;
B* pb = &bobj; //1
int* p1 = &bobj.a; //2 undefined, refers to base class member
int* p2 = &bobj.y.i; //3 undefined, refers to member’s member
A* pa = &bobj;
B bobj;
extern X xobj;
int* p3 = &xobj.i;
X xobj;
```

This example must reflect the rule:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any
>   non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor
>   begins execution results in undefined behavior.

But I've one doubt. If an implementation doesn't perform dynamic initialization for `//1`, `//2`, and `//3` in a static way, we have no undefined behavior at `//2` and `//3`, because (3.6.2/1):

> Constant initialization is performed:
>
> [...]
>
> — if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a **constructor** 
>   **call**, and if the initialization full-expression is a constant initializer for
>   the object;
>
> [...]
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called
>   static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic
>   initialization. **Static initialization shall be performed before** any
>   dynamic initialization takes place.

That is, we have that constructor has called before a non-static and base. So the result of that example is implementation defined.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: First of all, it is not clearly what are you asking about? The second thing i want to notice, that you can't do things like "extern B bobj; B* pb = &bobj;" because it would be linker error about unresolved external, so further reasoning seemed to be needless.

Comment: @ars he defines `bobj` later, that is fine

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question; `B bobj;` is dynamic initialization so it occurs after `p1` `p2` are initialized. Also this doesn't seem relevant, if the earlier quote is being correctly interpreted then the code has UB, end of story

Comment: I wonder if `&bobj.a` counts as "referring to" bobj.a, I don't see why this should cause UB since it is constant initialization.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, nor g++, nor VS2010 doesn't think that's fine( Am i miss something with that case?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why `B bobj` has a dynamic initialization? I've cited a rule for constant initialization from 3.6.2/1. Since I think `B bobj` is static initialization. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: `Y` has an explicit non-trivial constructor. `B` contains an `Y`, and thus has an implicit nontrivial constructor. `bobj` is a variable of type `B`, that is, a variable of a type with nontrivial constructor. Therefore it is dynamically initialized (by calling that nontrivial constructor).

Comment: There is no initialization full-expression in `B bobj;`

Comment: @celtschk It doesn't dependes on nontrivial contructor whether initialization is performed in a static or in a dynamic way.

Comment: I agree with Matt, what does *referring to* truly means? Is it same ase *taking a reference*? I don't think so. `p1` and `p2` are fine, `*p1` and `*p2` are not until we call the constructor.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That is `B bobj;` is definitely staic, but for instance `C cobj(1)` perform in a dynamic way, does it?

Comment: @ars [see it working](http://ideone.com/PzkzbD) , you must have made some sort of mis-transcription

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I think `B bobj;` is dynamic. It's not zero and it's not constant (the constructor `Y()` isn't even visible and it might contain calls which cannot be resolved at compile-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it may also invoke constexpr constructors", Y::Y() is not constexpr constructor so B bobj falls to dynamic initialization.

Comment: Basic idea is that B bobj is dynamically initialized which puts it after p1 and p2 in initialization order.

Comment: Yes, I've uderstood what you tried to say. Thank you.

Comment: One more question. Initialazation of `B bobj` will be perform in a static way if we declare the default constructor as a `constexpr`, won't it?

Comment: It would also have to be constexpr constructor. Meaning that it may not access any values that aren't constants. One could write a conditionally constexpr constructor where some parameters to it would make it not to be constexpr.