# Why Base Class Constructor not Called with Scope Resolution Operator

Tags: c++

Here I inherit a class and trying to call the base class constructor with scope resolution operator but it's showing error. Even we can access member function with same method `className::Fun();` why not with constructor?

```
class Base{
    public:
        Base(){
            cout << "A Constructor\n\n";
        }
};
class Derived:public Base{
    public:
        Derived(){
            Base::Base();
        }
};
```

I know I can call the base constructor by `Base();`
But what is the logic behind `Base::Base();` that is not allowing to do this.

I always worried to post question that it could be duplicate and I posted after failed to find the answer, If I still posting duplicate questions Please help me how I can search that my question is available on stackoverflow or not.

Comment: The base-class constructor is invoked automatically. You can invoke it, manually as well, but doing so will simply create a temporary object of the base class.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I know about that My question is about this `Base::Base();` what is the logic behind this?

Comment: When calling within the constructor of `Derived`, it is no longer initializing the inherited `Base`, instead it treats it as if you are calling the constructor for another object.

Comment: It is very strange, it gives an error on C++14 http://ideone.com/9lnDLG calling the scope resolution redundant, but C++4.9.2 works fine http://ideone.com/KiEw9b. I couldn't find anything in the Standard about scope resolution and constructors.

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
    Derived(){
        Base::Base();
    }
```

constructs a temporary `Base` in the constructor of the class and discards it. The line `Base::Base();` does not initialize the `Base` part of `Derived`.

The above code is equivalent to:

```
    Derived() : Base() {
             // ^^^ This initializes the Base part of Derived.
        Base::Base();
    }
```

What you need is just:

```
    Derived() {}
```

**Further Reading**

[Constructors and member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)
[Understanding class object construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470791/understanding-class-object-construction)

Comment: @R Sahu with you last code, the base constructor still calling just once.. It should be call twice, 1st when derived class object created,, 2nd When Derived constructor initialize list `Derived() : Base()` execute that is also calling the constructor of base class.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq, `Base::Base()` gets called only once because creation of an object is accomplished by calling the constructor.

Comment: @R Sahu are you sure you answered of my last question? I'm asking that why Base class constructor is not calling in initialize list?
`class Base{
 public:
  Base(){
   cout << "A Constructor\n\n";
  }
};
class Derived:public Base{
 public:
  Derived():Base(){
  }
};`
Output Should be 
`A Constructor   A Constructor`

Comment: @AsifMushtaq, Stop 1 and step 2 are really one step --- calling the constructor of `Derived` to construct the object.

Comment: @R Sahu just last question if it could clear the concept.. How it could be one step?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq, for a more thorough understanding, it will better for you to go through a tutorial or text book that explains the process of object construction and initialization in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the Base in the member initializer list:

```
class Derived:public Base{
    public:
        Derived()
        :  Base()
        {}
};
```

However, this one is pointless. You can omit it, since it is the default constructor of Base:

```
class Derived:public Base{
    public:
        Derived()
        {}
};
```

In your example you create an unused temporary Base object (However, the syntax is not correct).

Having:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
    public:
        Base(){
            std::cout << "A Constructor\n\n";
        }
};

class Derived:public Base{
    public:
        Derived(){
            Base();
        }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
A Constructor

A Constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to call a constructor directly, that's just how C++ works. It must be called internally as an object is created, or through placement new.

When you call `Base()` by itself without the qualifier, you're not calling the constructor, you're creating a temporary object. This calls the constructor obviously, but for the temporary object, not the one doing the call. If you output the address of the object in the constructor you'll see that they're not the same.

Comment: may be this stupid question, but we can call Base Class's member function with the same method. What is your view about that?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq the constructor is special. You can't call it the same way you call other member functions.

Comment: `className::foo();` this is a way of just static members. call without object. then why non-static member still working in derived class??

Comment: @AsifMushtaq the same syntax works for both static members of any class, and non-static members of a base class. *But not for constructors!* You can't call a constructor as a regular function call, no matter what syntax you use.